# whether there can be XML, appropriate XSD, having choice with maxOccurs = "1" and every elements with minOccurs="1"?

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb

I have valid XSD, But i can't make xml, appropriate it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="urn:hl7-org:v3"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="Main" type="Main"/>
    <xs:complexType name="Child1">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="f1" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Child2">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="f1" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Main">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element name="child1" type="Child1"
                            nillable="true"
                            minOccurs="1"
                            maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="child2" type="Child2"
                            nillable="true"
                            minOccurs="1"
                            maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

If this imposible, why schema is valid?
With JAXB generating sources for this schema, creating objects, but validation not passing - 
[Invalid content was found starting with element 'child1'. No child element is expected at this point.]

```
import cz.atria.common.datagenerator.ValueProvider;
import cz.atria.common.datagenerator.ValueProviderRandom;
import org.hl7.v3.Child1;
import org.hl7.v3.Main;
import org.hl7.v3.ObjectFactory;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import java.io.File;

public void test1() throws Exception {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Main.class.getPackage().getName());
    SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new File("D:\\cts2\\jaxbtest\\src\\main\\xsd\\schema1.xsd"));
    Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    ObjectFactory of = new ObjectFactory();
    marshaller.setSchema(schema);
    Main main = new Main();
    Child1 child1 = new Child1();

    child1.setF1("test");

    main.setChild1(child1);

    final ValidationEventHandler validationEventHandler = marshaller.getEventHandler();
    marshaller.setEventHandler(new ValidationEventHandler() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
            /*if(event.getLocator().getObject() instanceof Child1) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return validationEventHandler.handleEvent(event);
            }*/
            return validationEventHandler.handleEvent(event);
        }
    });

    System.out.println(marshaller.getEventHandler());
    marshaller.marshal(main, System.out);
}
```

Comment: Please post the XML you're trying to validate (preferable) or the Java code that's creating the objects whose XML representation is supposed to conform to this XSD.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What Your Problem Probably Is

Based on the same code in your question I am assuming that you have used an external bindings file like the following to get rid of the `JAXBElement` properties.

```
<jaxb:bindings
        xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
        jaxb:version="2.0"
        xmlns:xjc= "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" 
        jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">

    <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false">
        <xjc:simple />
    </jaxb:globalBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

This will give you a `Main` class that looks like the following:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "Main")
public class Main {

    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    protected Child2 child2;
    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    protected Child1 child1;

    ...

}
```

This will produce XML like the following, note the presence of the `child2` and `child1` elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Main xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
    <child2 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xsi:nil="true"/>
    <child1>
        <f1>test</f1>
    </child1>
</Main>
```

### How to Solve It

You need to put the `JAXBElement` properties back (to differentiate between the value being marshalled with `xsi:nil="true"` for null, or as an absent node as part of the choice).  This means you need to remove the `generateElementProperty="false"` from your external bindings file.  This will give you a Main class that looks like the following:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "Main")
public class Main {

    @XmlElementRef(name = "child2", namespace = "urn:hl7-org:v3", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<Child2> child2;
    @XmlElementRef(name = "child1", namespace = "urn:hl7-org:v3", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<Child1> child1;

    ...

}
```

This will produce XML like the following which validates correctly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Main xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
    <child1>
        <f1>test</f1>
    </child1>
</Main>
```

Answer (score 2):

The schema does not define an impossible situation.  Either of the following documents should be (and is) valid against this schema:

```
<tns:Main xmlns:tns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
  <tns:child1><tns:f1>Hi, mom.</tns:f1></tns:child1>
</tns:Main>

<tns:Main xmlns:tns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
  <tns:child2><tns:f1>Hi, dad.</tns:f1></tns:child2>
</tns:Main>
```

But in general, it is not a violation of the XSD spec for a schema to define a set of constraints which cannot all be satisfied at the same time (or, as you put it, to define an XML vocabulary which is impossible).  Requiring XSD processors to detect all cases of unsatisfiable constraints would impose a serious burden on implementations, and not necessarily a burden that anyone now knows how to meet at all, let alone meet with acceptable performance.

But if it is not obvious to you that the schema is satisfiable, then it seems likely that you have been under the impression that the schema means something different from what it does mean.  Since you don't tell us anything about that, there is very little anyone here can do to help you improve your understanding.  Good luck!